# Plot a continuous gaussian density along a curve (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have three data sets of positions of particles, with corresponding forces measured for these particles (data included here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/dd965bb86cfaad529136de74ea32e1d820230827150110/a6c826).

I plot the curves, with the forces displayed in the following way:

[image]

This is done using this code:

```
figure
num_colors = 256; rv = [1, 0, 0]; wv = [1, 1, 1]; bv = [0, 0, 1]; 
red_to_white  = [linspace(rv(1), wv(1), num_colors/2); linspace(rv(2), wv(2), num_colors/2); linspace(rv(3), wv(3), num_colors/2)]';
white_to_blue = [linspace(wv(1), bv(1), num_colors/2); linspace(wv(2), bv(2), num_colors/2); linspace(wv(3), bv(3), num_colors/2)]';
custom_colormap = [red_to_white; white_to_blue];
max_traction = 5; caxis_range = [-max_traction, max_traction];
hold on
patch([fliplr(xf_vec), nan], [t_vec, nan], [traction_f, nan], 'edgecolor', 'interp', 'linewidth', 8);
patch([fliplr(xb_vec), nan], [t_vec, nan], [traction_b, nan], 'edgecolor', 'interp', 'linewidth', 8);
patch([fliplr(xe_vec), nan], [t_vec, nan], [traction_e, nan], 'edgecolor', 'interp', 'linewidth', 8);

plot(fliplr(xf_vec), t_vec,'k',fliplr(xe_vec), t_vec,'k',fliplr(xb_vec), t_vec,'k','linewidth',1)
box on
colormap(custom_colormap); caxis(caxis_range); colorbar;
```

In this code I plot the forces (with respect to a colormap I provide) as a solid wide line, and on top of it the position curves.

What I wish to do is display the same figure where the forces spread like a gaussian around the position curve. The average will be the force measure, and at the edges of the gaussian (with some given width) the value will be zero and therefore the color will be white.

Comment: The term you're looking for might be "Violin Plot"? While that isn't a built-in plot type, there are [GitHub](https://github.com/bastibe/Violinplot-Matlab) and [FileExchange](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45134-violin-plot) examples people have made... If not could you please edit your question with some sort of [mcve] which uses random data instead of an external source and/or a simple image done in e.g. MS Paint of what your expected output is?